# zooming/panning framelayout that has imageviews

Tags: android

I have a framelayout that has a background image and  some imageviews. It also has some nested layouts (like Relative) in it. Anyways, what I am trying to achieve is the ability to zoom in/out and pan. I am used gesturedetection and the methods of setScaleX/setScaleY and translateX/tranlsateY

It does do the job partially but the translate gets the whole layout out of the screen sometimes and some other little problems.

Do you recommend a way of doing things or is there a code I can refer to?

Thank you

Comment: Have you read this - https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html. It is how Google recommends deal with zooming and panning

Comment: @Snake any luck on achieving this ? Please let me know , I too have the same requirement to implement

Comment: @Adi, I ended up using a library called photozoom (or something along these lines) and track the zoom onbackground image and propagate it to the rest

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom - it might help you.

**1. Create a new class "Touch"**

```
public class Touch implements OnTouchListener {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    dumpEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

// Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append("]");
}

// Determine the space between the first two fingers
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

// Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}}
```

**2. Change your Activity as followed**

```
 FrameLayout fm =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fm);
 fm.setOnTouchListener(new Touch());
```

Comment: This is zoom for one image. My question above is if you have layout with multiple images around. Not zooming in/out for single image

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is **quite similar** to the [KenBurns effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect).

There are a few libraries which you can refer to for **implementing this** or something which is similar to this.

1) [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView)

2) [JBKenBurns](https://github.com/jberlana/JBKenBurns)

3) [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/gotokatsuya/KenBurnsView)

I personally use one of these and never had any problem.

Good luck.